# Have two "project" sections in hugo academic?

Tags: r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I would like to duplicate the "Projects" section so that I have Projects and Portfolio sections. I have duplicated the `home/projects.md` file and made it `home/portfolio.md`. I have also created a subfolder `content/portfolio` just like `content/project`. However, on my main page, while I do have a section called "Portfolio", it just reproduces what is in the projects folder and ignores what is in the portfolio folder.

Here is the head matter of portfolio.md

```
+++
# A Projects section created with the Portfolio widget.
widget = "portfolio"  # See https://sourcethemes.com/academic/docs/page-builder/
headless = true  # This file represents a page section.
active = true  # Activate this widget? true/false
weight = 80  # Order that this section will appear.

title = "Portfolio"
subtitle = ""

[content]
  # Page type to display. E.g. project.
  page_type = "project"
```

How can I get this section to be separate and read files from the portfolio subfolder? A second, perhaps more complicated question is if it is possible to also have a separate tag taxonomy from the projects? But, that is obviously not my primary concern.

Comment: If u can share the code i can go through and give a solution for that.

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this. In the old version of academic theme you could specify the source folder, but no more.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first question, the created 'Portfolio' widget will look in the `project` folder because the `page_type` is defined as `project`. Change the `page_type` to the name of the folder you require i.e. `portfolio`.

`page_type` is not a very intuitive name for the folder definition, but that's the way it is!